# checking Field is on Focus

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

there are three edit field on my mainscreen i want to know which edit field is on focous.

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can have your Mainscreen class implement FocusChangeListener.
If you instantiate your Edit controls as Focusable, and implement the listener:

```
public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType)
{
    if(field == YourEditField1)
    {
    }
    else if (field == YourEditField2)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isFocus

public boolean isFocus()
Determines if this field currently has the focus.

Returns:
True if this field has the focus; otherwise, false.

Since: JDE 4.2.0